# InnoDB IO Capacity on Amazon AWS EBS GP2 Volumes

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-ec2

I have MariaDB pointing to a data directory that's a mounted Amazon AWS EBS GP2 volume. No other process will be using that volume.

The AWS console lists the volume as having 120 / 3000 IOPS. My understanding is that 120 is the baseline, burstable to 3000 IOPS. My installation is currently using the MariaDB defaults:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like 'innodb_io_%';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| innodb_io_capacity     | 200   |
| innodb_io_capacity_max | 2000  |
+------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Would updating those values to be `innodb_io_capacity = 120` and `innodb_io_capacity_max = 3000` be the right settings to get the full performance benefit?

Comment: leave it as is. 200 - default value for MySQL (any).

Comment: I suspect the relationship between the two pairs of settings is very nebulous.